# Change text on Hover using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change a navigation element from 'ME' to <ME> on hover using JQuery. Here's what I'm trying:
[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/OMiBiNi/1/edit)

However, it's permanently hiding my original text. Does anyone have an idea as to what I'm doing wrong? (I'm super new to JQuery/ JS in general)

Comment: Can I ask exactly what it is you're trying to do with your list elements in that example? Just add a hover state to each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/eticAqI/1/edit)

Try this. I have edited your code

```
$( function() {
  var text;
  $("#topnav li ").hover(
    function () {
      text=$(this).find("a").text();
     $(this).find("a").text($(this).attr('full'));
    },
    function () {
       $(this).find("a").text(text);
    }
  );
});
```

Hope this helps
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Classical case of `no js required`, you could use CSS pseudo classes, specifically:

- `:hover`
- `:before`
- `:after`

<kbd>**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vvkLT/1/)**</kbd>

```
li a:before {
    content: "<";
    display: none;
}

li a:after {
    content: ">";
    display: none;
}

li a:hover:before {
    display: inline;
}

li a:hover:after {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: That depends on the OP's browser requirements (not mentioning any names…) [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent)

Comment: That's true, but I think it's safe to say, that browser support for IE7 is a more and more exotic requirement.

Comment: I agree - just thought I'd mention in case the OP has a valid reason for requesting a jQuery/Javascript solution.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Nirazul, if you can, go for a pure css solution.

If you can't, just remember that you are:

1. obtaining the value a of a attribute of the li
2. replacing the text of link inside of the selected li with its contents
3. reversing the operation on handlerOut

So:

```
$( function() { 
  $("#topnav li").hover(
    function () {
      var myLi = $(this);
      myLi.attr('small', $('a', myLi).text());
      $('a', myLi).text(myLi.attr('full'));
    },
    function () {
       var myLi = $(this);
       $('a',myLi).text(myLi.attr('small'));
    }
  );
});
```

Updated [example](http://jsbin.com/iKEqowo/1/edit).