# Display another text/letter on hover

Tags: jquery, css, effect

I want to hide one letter, and display another in a link, with different style of the letters-on-hover, of course. For example:

This is a...

```
...normal link.
```

And this is a...

```
...hovêrêd lînk.
```

How to achieve this? Thank you.

***Edit:***
**Yes, a needed clarification** — I want only to change specific letters (i ➛ î, e ➛ ê) and to change style on hover, not the entire link, because the link is same both normal and hovered.

The guy who posted this

```
$('.class').hover(function()
{
$(this).data('i', $(this).text());
$(this).text("î");
},
function()
{
$(this).text($(this).data('i'));
}
);
```

Was close to solution. Only this piece of code changes the entire link on hover, not just letters.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Nothing yet. I don’t know from where to start. That’s why I didn’t post any examples.

Comment: It would be helpful to clarify some things, such as by "different style" do you mean change all letters that have an accented form to that form? What if they've got multiple accented forms?

Comment: Also, you can find how to do the on-hover stuff in many other questions, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301138/change-text-on-hover-using-jquery

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
$('#link').hover(function(){
  $(this).text('...hovêrêd lînk.');
},function(){
  $(this).text('normal link..');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="link">normal link..</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well that was fun. Here's something to randomly do some letter subtitutions with accents. This is probably too aggressive for what you're after, but you could remove the letter substitutions you don't want.

```js
var diacriticsMap = [
        {'base':'A', 'letters':['\u0041','\u24B6','\uFF21','\u00C0','\u00C1','\u00C2','\u1EA6','\u1EA4','\u1EAA','\u1EA8','\u00C3','\u0100','\u0102','\u1EB0','\u1EAE','\u1EB4','\u1EB2','\u0226','\u01E0','\u00C4','\u01DE','\u1EA2','\u00C5','\u01FA','\u01CD','\u0200','\u0202','\u1EA0','\u1EAC','\u1EB6','\u1E00','\u0104','\u023A','\u2C6F']},
        {'base':'AA','letters':['\uA732']},
        {'base':'AE','letters':['\u00C6','\u01FC','\u01E2']},
        {'base':'AO','letters':['\uA734']},
        {'base':'AU','letters':['\uA736']},
        {'base':'AV','letters':['\uA738','\uA73A']},
        {'base':'AY','letters':['\uA73C']},
        {'base':'B', 'letters':['\u0042','\u24B7','\uFF22','\u1E02','\u1E04','\u1E06','\u0243','\u0182','\u0181']},
        {'base':'C', 'letters':['\u0043','\u24B8','\uFF23','\u0106','\u0108','\u010A','\u010C','\u00C7','\u1E08','\u0187','\u023B','\uA73E']},
        {'base':'D', 'letters':['\u0044','\u24B9','\uFF24','\u1E0A','\u010E','\u1E0C','\u1E10','\u1E12','\u1E0E','\u0110','\u018B','\u018A','\u0189','\uA779']},
        {'base':'DZ','letters':['\u01F1','\u01C4']},
        {'base':'Dz','letters':['\u01F2','\u01C5']},
        {'base':'E', 'letters':['\u0045','\u24BA','\uFF25','\u00C8','\u00C9','\u00CA','\u1EC0','\u1EBE','\u1EC4','\u1EC2','\u1EBC','\u0112','\u1E14','\u1E16','\u0114','\u0116','\u00CB','\u1EBA','\u011A','\u0204','\u0206','\u1EB8','\u1EC6','\u0228','\u1E1C','\u0118','\u1E18','\u1E1A','\u0190','\u018E']},
        {'base':'F', 'letters':['\u0046','\u24BB','\uFF26','\u1E1E','\u0191','\uA77B']},
        {'base':'G', 'letters':['\u0047','\u24BC','\uFF27','\u01F4','\u011C','\u1E20','\u011E','\u0120','\u01E6','\u0122','\u01E4','\u0193','\uA7A0','\uA77D','\uA77E']},
        {'base':'H', 'letters':['\u0048','\u24BD','\uFF28','\u0124','\u1E22','\u1E26','\u021E','\u1E24','\u1E28','\u1E2A','\u0126','\u2C67','\u2C75','\uA78D']},
        {'base':'I', 'letters':['\u0049','\u24BE','\uFF29','\u00CC','\u00CD','\u00CE','\u0128','\u012A','\u012C','\u0130','\u00CF','\u1E2E','\u1EC8','\u01CF','\u0208','\u020A','\u1ECA','\u012E','\u1E2C','\u0197']},
        {'base':'J', 'letters':['\u004A','\u24BF','\uFF2A','\u0134','\u0248']},
        {'base':'K', 'letters':['\u004B','\u24C0','\uFF2B','\u1E30','\u01E8','\u1E32','\u0136','\u1E34','\u0198','\u2C69','\uA740','\uA742','\uA744','\uA7A2']},
        {'base':'L', 'letters':['\u004C','\u24C1','\uFF2C','\u013F','\u0139','\u013D','\u1E36','\u1E38','\u013B','\u1E3C','\u1E3A','\u0141','\u023D','\u2C62','\u2C60','\uA748','\uA746','\uA780']},
        {'base':'LJ','letters':['\u01C7']},
        {'base':'Lj','letters':['\u01C8']},
        {'base':'M', 'letters':['\u004D','\u24C2','\uFF2D','\u1E3E','\u1E40','\u1E42','\u2C6E','\u019C']},
        {'base':'N', 'letters':['\u004E','\u24C3','\uFF2E','\u01F8','\u0143','\u00D1','\u1E44','\u0147','\u1E46','\u0145','\u1E4A','\u1E48','\u0220','\u019D','\uA790','\uA7A4']},
        {'base':'NJ','letters':['\u01CA']},
        {'base':'Nj','letters':['\u01CB']},
        {'base':'O', 'letters':['\u004F','\u24C4','\uFF2F','\u00D2','\u00D3','\u00D4','\u1ED2','\u1ED0','\u1ED6','\u1ED4','\u00D5','\u1E4C','\u022C','\u1E4E','\u014C','\u1E50','\u1E52','\u014E','\u022E','\u0230','\u00D6','\u022A','\u1ECE','\u0150','\u01D1','\u020C','\u020E','\u01A0','\u1EDC','\u1EDA','\u1EE0','\u1EDE','\u1EE2','\u1ECC','\u1ED8','\u01EA','\u01EC','\u00D8','\u01FE','\u0186','\u019F','\uA74A','\uA74C']},
        {'base':'OI','letters':['\u01A2']},
        {'base':'OO','letters':['\uA74E']},
        {'base':'OU','letters':['\u0222']},
        {'base':'OE','letters':['\u008C','\u0152']},
        {'base':'oe','letters':['\u009C','\u0153']},
        {'base':'P', 'letters':['\u0050','\u24C5','\uFF30','\u1E54','\u1E56','\u01A4','\u2C63','\uA750','\uA752','\uA754']},
        {'base':'Q', 'letters':['\u0051','\u24C6','\uFF31','\uA756','\uA758','\u024A']},
        {'base':'R', 'letters':['\u0052','\u24C7','\uFF32','\u0154','\u1E58','\u0158','\u0210','\u0212','\u1E5A','\u1E5C','\u0156','\u1E5E','\u024C','\u2C64','\uA75A','\uA7A6','\uA782']},
        {'base':'S', 'letters':['\u0053','\u24C8','\uFF33','\u1E9E','\u015A','\u1E64','\u015C','\u1E60','\u0160','\u1E66','\u1E62','\u1E68','\u0218','\u015E','\u2C7E','\uA7A8','\uA784']},
        {'base':'T', 'letters':['\u0054','\u24C9','\uFF34','\u1E6A','\u0164','\u1E6C','\u021A','\u0162','\u1E70','\u1E6E','\u0166','\u01AC','\u01AE','\u023E','\uA786']},
        {'base':'TZ','letters':['\uA728']},
        {'base':'U', 'letters':['\u0055','\u24CA','\uFF35','\u00D9','\u00DA','\u00DB','\u0168','\u1E78','\u016A','\u1E7A','\u016C','\u00DC','\u01DB','\u01D7','\u01D5','\u01D9','\u1EE6','\u016E','\u0170','\u01D3','\u0214','\u0216','\u01AF','\u1EEA','\u1EE8','\u1EEE','\u1EEC','\u1EF0','\u1EE4','\u1E72','\u0172','\u1E76','\u1E74','\u0244']},
        {'base':'V', 'letters':['\u0056','\u24CB','\uFF36','\u1E7C','\u1E7E','\u01B2','\uA75E','\u0245']},
        {'base':'VY','letters':['\uA760']},
        {'base':'W', 'letters':['\u0057','\u24CC','\uFF37','\u1E80','\u1E82','\u0174','\u1E86','\u1E84','\u1E88','\u2C72']},
        {'base':'X', 'letters':['\u0058','\u24CD','\uFF38','\u1E8A','\u1E8C']},
        {'base':'Y', 'letters':['\u0059','\u24CE','\uFF39','\u1EF2','\u00DD','\u0176','\u1EF8','\u0232','\u1E8E','\u0178','\u1EF6','\u1EF4','\u01B3','\u024E','\u1EFE']},
        {'base':'Z', 'letters':['\u005A','\u24CF','\uFF3A','\u0179','\u1E90','\u017B','\u017D','\u1E92','\u1E94','\u01B5','\u0224','\u2C7F','\u2C6B','\uA762']},
        {'base':'a', 'letters':['\u0061','\u24D0','\uFF41','\u1E9A','\u00E0','\u00E1','\u00E2','\u1EA7','\u1EA5','\u1EAB','\u1EA9','\u00E3','\u0101','\u0103','\u1EB1','\u1EAF','\u1EB5','\u1EB3','\u0227','\u01E1','\u00E4','\u01DF','\u1EA3','\u00E5','\u01FB','\u01CE','\u0201','\u0203','\u1EA1','\u1EAD','\u1EB7','\u1E01','\u0105','\u2C65','\u0250']},
        {'base':'aa','letters':['\uA733']},
        {'base':'ae','letters':['\u00E6','\u01FD','\u01E3']},
        {'base':'ao','letters':['\uA735']},
        {'base':'au','letters':['\uA737']},
        {'base':'av','letters':['\uA739','\uA73B']},
        {'base':'ay','letters':['\uA73D']},
        {'base':'b', 'letters':['\u0062','\u24D1','\uFF42','\u1E03','\u1E05','\u1E07','\u0180','\u0183','\u0253']},
        {'base':'c', 'letters':['\u0063','\u24D2','\uFF43','\u0107','\u0109','\u010B','\u010D','\u00E7','\u1E09','\u0188','\u023C','\uA73F','\u2184']},
        {'base':'d', 'letters':['\u0064','\u24D3','\uFF44','\u1E0B','\u010F','\u1E0D','\u1E11','\u1E13','\u1E0F','\u0111','\u018C','\u0256','\u0257','\uA77A']},
        {'base':'dz','letters':['\u01F3','\u01C6']},
        {'base':'e', 'letters':['\u0065','\u24D4','\uFF45','\u00E8','\u00E9','\u00EA','\u1EC1','\u1EBF','\u1EC5','\u1EC3','\u1EBD','\u0113','\u1E15','\u1E17','\u0115','\u0117','\u00EB','\u1EBB','\u011B','\u0205','\u0207','\u1EB9','\u1EC7','\u0229','\u1E1D','\u0119','\u1E19','\u1E1B','\u0247','\u025B','\u01DD']},
        {'base':'f', 'letters':['\u0066','\u24D5','\uFF46','\u1E1F','\u0192','\uA77C']},
        {'base':'g', 'letters':['\u0067','\u24D6','\uFF47','\u01F5','\u011D','\u1E21','\u011F','\u0121','\u01E7','\u0123','\u01E5','\u0260','\uA7A1','\u1D79','\uA77F']},
        {'base':'h', 'letters':['\u0068','\u24D7','\uFF48','\u0125','\u1E23','\u1E27','\u021F','\u1E25','\u1E29','\u1E2B','\u1E96','\u0127','\u2C68','\u2C76','\u0265']},
        {'base':'hv','letters':['\u0195']},
        {'base':'i', 'letters':['\u0069','\u24D8','\uFF49','\u00EC','\u00ED','\u00EE','\u0129','\u012B','\u012D','\u00EF','\u1E2F','\u1EC9','\u01D0','\u0209','\u020B','\u1ECB','\u012F','\u1E2D','\u0268','\u0131']},
        {'base':'j', 'letters':['\u006A','\u24D9','\uFF4A','\u0135','\u01F0','\u0249']},
        {'base':'k', 'letters':['\u006B','\u24DA','\uFF4B','\u1E31','\u01E9','\u1E33','\u0137','\u1E35','\u0199','\u2C6A','\uA741','\uA743','\uA745','\uA7A3']},
        {'base':'l', 'letters':['\u006C','\u24DB','\uFF4C','\u0140','\u013A','\u013E','\u1E37','\u1E39','\u013C','\u1E3D','\u1E3B','\u017F','\u0142','\u019A','\u026B','\u2C61','\uA749','\uA781','\uA747']},
        {'base':'lj','letters':['\u01C9']},
        {'base':'m', 'letters':['\u006D','\u24DC','\uFF4D','\u1E3F','\u1E41','\u1E43','\u0271','\u026F']},
        {'base':'n', 'letters':['\u006E','\u24DD','\uFF4E','\u01F9','\u0144','\u00F1','\u1E45','\u0148','\u1E47','\u0146','\u1E4B','\u1E49','\u019E','\u0272','\u0149','\uA791','\uA7A5']},
        {'base':'nj','letters':['\u01CC']},
        {'base':'o', 'letters':['\u006F','\u24DE','\uFF4F','\u00F2','\u00F3','\u00F4','\u1ED3','\u1ED1','\u1ED7','\u1ED5','\u00F5','\u1E4D','\u022D','\u1E4F','\u014D','\u1E51','\u1E53','\u014F','\u022F','\u0231','\u00F6','\u022B','\u1ECF','\u0151','\u01D2','\u020D','\u020F','\u01A1','\u1EDD','\u1EDB','\u1EE1','\u1EDF','\u1EE3','\u1ECD','\u1ED9','\u01EB','\u01ED','\u00F8','\u01FF','\u0254','\uA74B','\uA74D','\u0275']},
        {'base':'oi','letters':['\u01A3']},
        {'base':'ou','letters':['\u0223']},
        {'base':'oo','letters':['\uA74F']},
        {'base':'p','letters':['\u0070','\u24DF','\uFF50','\u1E55','\u1E57','\u01A5','\u1D7D','\uA751','\uA753','\uA755']},
        {'base':'q','letters':['\u0071','\u24E0','\uFF51','\u024B','\uA757','\uA759']},
        {'base':'r','letters':['\u0072','\u24E1','\uFF52','\u0155','\u1E59','\u0159','\u0211','\u0213','\u1E5B','\u1E5D','\u0157','\u1E5F','\u024D','\u027D','\uA75B','\uA7A7','\uA783']},
        {'base':'s','letters':['\u0073','\u24E2','\uFF53','\u00DF','\u015B','\u1E65','\u015D','\u1E61','\u0161','\u1E67','\u1E63','\u1E69','\u0219','\u015F','\u023F','\uA7A9','\uA785','\u1E9B']},
        {'base':'t','letters':['\u0074','\u24E3','\uFF54','\u1E6B','\u1E97','\u0165','\u1E6D','\u021B','\u0163','\u1E71','\u1E6F','\u0167','\u01AD','\u0288','\u2C66','\uA787']},
        {'base':'tz','letters':['\uA729']},
        {'base':'u','letters':['\u0075','\u24E4','\uFF55','\u00F9','\u00FA','\u00FB','\u0169','\u1E79','\u016B','\u1E7B','\u016D','\u00FC','\u01DC','\u01D8','\u01D6','\u01DA','\u1EE7','\u016F','\u0171','\u01D4','\u0215','\u0217','\u01B0','\u1EEB','\u1EE9','\u1EEF','\u1EED','\u1EF1','\u1EE5','\u1E73','\u0173','\u1E77','\u1E75','\u0289']},
        {'base':'v','letters':['\u0076','\u24E5','\uFF56','\u1E7D','\u1E7F','\u028B','\uA75F','\u028C']},
        {'base':'vy','letters':['\uA761']},
        {'base':'w','letters':['\u0077','\u24E6','\uFF57','\u1E81','\u1E83','\u0175','\u1E87','\u1E85','\u1E98','\u1E89','\u2C73']},
        {'base':'x','letters':['\u0078','\u24E7','\uFF58','\u1E8B','\u1E8D']},
        {'base':'y','letters':['\u0079','\u24E8','\uFF59','\u1EF3','\u00FD','\u0177','\u1EF9','\u0233','\u1E8F','\u00FF','\u1EF7','\u1E99','\u1EF5','\u01B4','\u024F','\u1EFF']},
        {'base':'z','letters':['\u007A','\u24E9','\uFF5A','\u017A','\u1E91','\u017C','\u017E','\u1E93','\u1E95','\u01B6','\u0225','\u0240','\u2C6C','\uA763']}
    ];
// Sort by length, so 'a' replace doesn't conflict with 'ae'. You could just order them properly in the array, and skip this step.
diacriticsMap.sort(function(a,b) {
 return b.base.length - a.base.length;
});

function uglifyString(stringValue) {
 for (var i = 0; i < diacriticsMap.length; i++) {
  var substituteMap = diacriticsMap[i];
  var re = new RegExp(substituteMap.base,"g");
  
  var letterIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * substituteMap.letters.length);
  
  stringValue = stringValue.replace(re, substituteMap.letters[letterIndex]);
 }
 return stringValue;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.flip-me").each(function(index, el) {
    $(el).data("fullText", $(el).text());
    $(el).data("hoverText", uglifyString($(el).text()));
  });
  
  $("a.flip-me").hover(
    function(inEvent) {
      var flippedText = $(this).data("hoverText");
      if (flippedText) {
        $(this).text(flippedText);
      }      
    },
    function(outEvent) {
      var normalText = $(this).data("fullText");
      if (normalText) {
        $(this).text(normalText);
      }
    }
  );
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a class="flip-me" href="#">A link to the past</a></li>
  <li><a class="flip-me" href="#">Ocarina of Time</a></li>
  <li><a class="flip-me" href="#">Who is Zelda?</a></li>
  <li><a class="flip-me" href="#">Mickey Mouse</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it merely me, or this doesn’t work? I ran the code snippet and hovered over links, but nothing happens.

Comment: I've tested in chrome and edge. seems to work. Is it unclear what the code is doing/is it helpful?

Comment: Also, letter substitutions copied from http://stackoverflow.com/a/18391901/405180

Comment: @De1an what browser and language are you using? maybe if you tried running it, or tinkering with it outside the snippet runner.

Comment: Hello, I’m using Firefox and English/Serbian. I check this page regularly, but no one seems to have created a propriate solution for this specific problem.

Comment: @De1an I've reordered the declarations in the snippet above, as i was getting an error when I put it in a jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/evdrwqkf/). Check if it works now.

Comment: @De1an was this solution helpful for you? Please accept it if it worked for you

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery this can be done easily. Below is the example code for the same.

**HTML CODE**

```
<p class="c-hover">Normal Text</p> 
//give the class of "c-hover to the element you want to change"
```

**JS CODE**

```
$('.c-hover').hover(function(){
 $(this).text('Hover Text'); //text to be shown on hover state
},function(){
 $(this).text('Normal Text'); //text to be seen when not in hover state
});
```

Comment: Similar code was posted earlier. More precisely what I need is... ...normal link - **normal link**, hovered link: **normâl lînk** (when hovered _anywhere_ on “normal link”). Therefore, only “a” and “i” to change on hovered “normal link”, and to have a different style from the rest of the “norm_l l_nk”. :-)

Comment: i got your point by why cant u change the entire text on hover and write "a" "i" different in hovered text? Just a doubt in my mind.

Comment: Because I want different styles for those two tough-to-change little guys “a” and “i”. :-)